# Resize Rows using if else in GAS

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am working on a script in which if a cell in col10 has a value it will auto resize the the row otherwise it will set the row height, in this case the row height is 72

The following image is a screenshot of what I am trying to achieve here

[image]

```
function reset_rows_auto() {
      
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet(); 
    
    var lastRow = sheet.getMaxRows().toString();
    var lastRow = lastRow.replace(".0",""); 
    
    for (var i = 1; i < lastRow; i++) {
      
      var abc = sheet.getRange(i, 10) //col10
      
    if (abc != "") {
      
        sheet.autoResizeRows([i],1)
    
        } 
      
    else if (abc == "") {
     
     sheet.setRowHeight([i], 72)
        
        }
      } 
    }
```

Every time I run the script its, only auto resizing the row and not setting the row height of rows which have blank cell in Col10. I am not being able to figure the error out here, could anyone please help

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several typos in your code.

Try this:

```
function reset_rows_auto() {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet(); 

  var lastRow = sheet.getMaxRows();

  for (var i = 1; i < lastRow; i++) {
  
    var abc = sheet.getRange(i, 10).getDisplayValue(); //col10
  
    if (abc != "") {
  
      sheet.autoResizeRows(i, 1);

    } 
  
    else {
 
      sheet.setRowHeight(i, 72);
    
    }
  } 
}
```